# Log several ranges

Tags: excel, vba

Currently my code is trying to log the old values when the excel clock starts running. the old value are logged into a row into a separate sheet. Same thing, when the clock stops running, the new values are logged into the log sheet into a new row. Right now, the code only works for the new values, it seems that the code doesn't record theold values properly. If you have a fix for this, it woyuld be appreciated. Also, i want to be able to log several ranges at a time, right now my code can only handle one range. If someone has a fix for this, it would be appreciated. Here is my code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static startTime As Double ' Stores the start time
    Dim elapsedTime As Double ' Stores the elapsed time
    Dim logSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oldValues As Variant
    Dim newValues As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim numColumns As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the log sheet (change the name if needed)
    Set logSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log - Ratio")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Start the stopwatch and capture old values
        startTime = Timer
        oldValues = Me.Range("O32:CL32").Value
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Stop the stopwatch, capture new values, and log the information
        elapsedTime = Timer - startTime
        newValues = Me.Range("O32:CL32").Value
        rowNum = logSheet.Cells(logSheet.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        numColumns = Me.Range("O32:CL32").Columns.count ' Calculate the number of columns

        ' Log the information in the "Log - Ratio" sheet
        logSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = Now ' Timestamp
        logSheet.Cells(rowNum, 2).Value = Application.UserName ' User
        logSheet.Cells(rowNum, 3).Value = "O32:CL32" ' Cell range

        ' Log old values
        For i = 1 To numColumns
            logSheet.Cells(rowNum, 3 + i).Value = Me.Cells(32, 14 + i).Value ' Old values
        Next i

        ' Log new values
        For i = 1 To numColumns
            logSheet.Cells(rowNum, 3 + numColumns + i).Value = newValues(1, i) ' New values
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Set a Watch on "Me.Range("B1")" and confirm that it really is "Nothing".

Comment: `oldValues` needs to be a Global if you want its value to be preserved between calls.  What is the purpose of the timer?

Comment: Are the additional ranges to be logged all single-row ranges?  Please add some examples of the other ranges

Comment: The timer is to trigger the code.  Previously, I had the issue that the code was only triggered when  a manual change occured, but i wanted to log all changes, specially for changes related to  a formula recalculating because i make updates to the sheet monthly by importing new values and the formula recalculates every time i make the update. So the timer was to set the  moment when i import the new values. For the ranges, think of a table with one row representing a time-series variable, for instance: varibale X is from range A1:M1, variable y is from range A2:M2, etc..- Tim williams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```vb
Dim RangeValues As Object 'global (or could use Static inside the event handler)
Dim startTime

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim elapsedTime As Double ' Stores the elapsed time
    Dim logSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oldValues As Variant, newValues As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Long, numColumns As Long
    Dim i As Long, LogRanges, el

    'assuming all ranges to be logged are single-row and >1 cell...
    LogRanges = Array("A6:E6", "A8:E8")

    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
        Case "B1" 'B1 was selected
            ' Start the stopwatch and capture old values
            startTime = Now
            Set RangeValues = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
            For Each el In LogRanges 'capture current values from each range
                With Me.Range(el)
                    RangeValues(.Address) = .Value
                End With
            Next el
        Case "C1" 'C1 was selected
            ' Stop the stopwatch, capture new values, and log the information
            Set logSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log - Ratio")
            rowNum = logSheet.Cells(logSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            For Each el In LogRanges
                With Me.Range(el)
                    oldValues = RangeValues(.Address)
                    newValues = .Value
                End With
                numColumns = UBound(oldValues, 2)
                With logSheet.Rows(rowNum)
                    .Cells(1).Value = startTime
                    .Cells(1).Offset(1).Value = Now
                    .Cells(2).Resize(2).Value = Application.UserName
                    .Cells(3).Resize(2).Value = el 'range address
                    .Cells(4).Value = "OLD"
                    .Cells(5).Resize(1, numColumns).Value = oldValues
                    .Cells(4).Offset(1).Value = "NEW"
                    .Cells(5).Offset(1).Resize(1, numColumns).Value = newValues
                End With
                rowNum = rowNum + 2
            Next el
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim Williams, this is awesome it works. The only setback is that it doesn't log the old values, could you fix it so that it logs both the old and new values. For instance: step 1) start timer and log the old values into the log sheet, step 2) stop timer and log the new values into the log sheet

Comment: Works fine for me - logs both old and new values

Comment: for me it only works when i clikc on C1 to stop the timer, then it logs the value. B1 to start the clock and log the value do not. Tim williams.

Comment: I think i understand what's happening. It logs both the old values and new values on the same row. Could you adjust it to log the old value in one row and the new value in the row underneath ? Tim Williams

Comment: I was following your posted code.  It's not clear how it should look instead - should the values in A-C on the log sheet be repeated for old and new values?  Maybe you can mock up how it should look and post a screenshot...

Comment: I apologize if it was unclear. Indeed, the values in A-C should be repeated. Preferably i would add another column D labelled old values and new values to make it clear which is which. Here is a screenshot below to make it clearer.2024-03-20 12:21 UserName O32:CL32 OLD values
2024-03-20 12:21 UserName O32:CL32 NEW values
2024-03-20 12:21 UserName O34:CL34 OLD values
2024-03-20 12:21 UserName O34:CL34 NEW values

Comment: Same timestamp for both rows?

Comment: Different timestamps depending on when i click on B1 when the timer start and when i click on C1 to stop the timer

Comment: see edits above.

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.  Maybe review your past questions also and accept any answers there...